# wxBufferedDC can get to work

Tags: wxwidgets

hi im using wxWidgets in c++, I have been drawing outside of paint events using wcClientDC which caused flicker. I would like help using wxBufferedDC. I literally just replaced wxClientDC with wxBufferedDC, I taut this would work but the code does not compile due to ghe construtor arguments.

my working code is :

wxClientDC dc (panel2);

replaced with:

wxBufferedDC dc (panel2);

What do I need to do inorder to use wxBufferedDC?

Answer (score 0):

To fix flicker, you must avoid drawing from outside your `wxEVT_PAINT` handler, buffering drawing doesn't help much if you are going to redraw the window soon anyhow. So instead of replacing `wxClientDC` with `wxBufferedDC`, get rid of `wxClientDC` entirely and use `wxAutoBufferedPaintDC` instead of `wxPaintDC`.

Comment: Hi thanks for response. I am not I understand what you saying. Currently on a timer trigger event I update a graph on a panel. With wxClient it caused flicker. How would I use wxAutoBufferedDC in my time triggered event?

Comment: You would `Refresh()` the window from the timer event and then paint it as usual.

Comment: Can I not just refresh my panel?

Comment: Thanks VZ for your assistance, I ended up using wxBufferedPaintDC and setting EVT_ERASEBACKGROUND Blank. I could not get wxAutoBufferedPaintDC working because of some call to wxBACKGROUNDStyle ???. But letting me know about refresh() that really helped me out.

Comment: The background style assert should really be self-explanatory: you should call `SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_PAINT)` to avoid erasing the background twice, what is the problem?